# Getting a white space at bottom of iPhone X screen (Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I'm using Xcode 9 for my project and I'm getting a white space at the bottom, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Also I'm using storyboard to design with 4 inches (iphone 5s/SE) as layout.

How to avoid the white space?

Comment: You would need to provide code and constraints for us to help you. I would look at your constraints first, you probably have something wrong with that. But as the question is constructed I can just guess.

Comment: @Harish : You should accept correct answer as per the stackoverflow guidelines so that other people with similar issue can get help!

Answer (score 104):

Your `bottom constraints` should be from `view` not from the `bottom layout guide` or `safe area`(xcode 9 specific) and your distance should be zero.

Default it was pinned with `layout guides`, so give it with `view` !

Refer below screenshot for better understanding,

[image]

to open this dialogue, click drop down icon of field contains `0`!

You can do same for `top constraint` also!

**Update :**

Second main important thing,

you should use storyboard for your launch or splashscreen. If you are using launch image then replace it by new launch image of `xcode 9` and it have option for the image of iphone x.

Then you will not found white space any more!

Refer below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thank You. Worked.

Comment: @Lion This might remove the white space, but isn't it correct to give the constraints with respect to layout guides ? Also now there's safe area which could be used instead of layout guides.

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work. I am using latest Xcode 9.

Comment: On interface designer it seems OK but when I run the app on simulator I am still getting white space at the bottom. Maybe on real device it will be OK.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, tnx.

Answer (score 21):

This white space is your main view. If you want your image view to fill the whole area, pin it with 0 space to the superview, not to Bottom Layout Guide or Safe Area. To achieve this, select to view scene in storyboard as iPhone X and pin the image view as below:

[image]

It is also possible to pin the bottom of image view to superview when not in iPhone X mode: when you pin by dragging with Ctrl, when the list of constaints appears press Option key (alt) and you will see "Bottom Space to Container Margin".

Comment: yeah, but I's using 4" as my layout not iphone x layout

Comment: Why cannot you switch to View as iPhone X, pin it, and then go back to 4''?

Comment: Anyways, I edited my answer, it's also possible to do that not in iPhone X view, using "option" key.

Comment: Thank You. I found it. The constraint was added to the safe area. After added to the view it works.

Comment: No problem. It's harder to pin it to the superview rather than Safe Area if you have not selected "View as: iPhone X", so this is a little hint:)

Comment: If that's the correct answer, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the two answers above worked for me. Only setting

```
 scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

I have a stackView inside my scrollView and the elements in the stackView have fixed sizes, so I have no need to inset adjustment and this works.

Credit goes to [How to get rid of safeAreaInsets on UIScrollview (iOS 11, iPhoneX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595621/how-to-get-rid-of-safeareainsets-on-uiscrollview-ios-11-iphonex)

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

1) Select image for which you are setting up constraints

2) Go to Attribute inspector in the right panel

3) Select `Scale to Fill` as `Content Mode`