# How to get rid of white space at bottom of Launch Screen on iPhone X

Tags: ios, launch-screen, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

There is a white space at the bottom of the launch screen on iPhone X even though I am using safe area.

[image: White space at the bottom]

On interface builder it seems OK:

[image: On interface builder]

I am using superview for my constraints:

[image: Constraints]

Here is the view hierarchy:

[image: View hierarchy]

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322150/getting-a-white-space-at-bottom-of-iphone-x-screenxcode-9

Comment: Set your image view's top constraint to top of your superview and bottom constraint to bottom of your superview, not to top/bottom layout guide or safe layout guide.

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the image view contained in some other view? Probably its constraints are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

***The white space you see is the controller default view background color.***

The problem is when you try to add a top/bottom constraint to any view. It adds the constraint to the Layout Guide **(default behavior)**.

> To over-write that. you can click the arrow next to the constrait
>   constant value. which shows the views that you can connect against.
>   obviously you need to connect with the one with the largest distance
>   value, **and set the constant value to 0**.

[image]

**Same applies to the launch screen controller.**

If you have the constraint already added. you can change that from the constraint **Attributes Inspector**:

[image]

If you have a **top** constraint you need to choose the **First Baseline**. and if you have a **bottom** constraint you need to choose **Last Baseline**

Comment: I have tried this but in simulator there is still white space.

Answer (score 0):

If Using LaunchScreen then do the following

first setup LaunchImage with proper size and reference to correct assest.

Remove Launch screen File or set nil
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This just solved my issue!
Try to pick the SuperView option like the screenshot shows. I had the same issue for also the top of the screen, and I did the same procedure, and worked!

[image: XCode screenshoot]