# White space on bottom iPhone X Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I know that another question with same issue is there but the answers didn't solve my problem.

[image]

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322603/3081929) but still, I am getting the white space.

[image]

My bottom constraints are with SuperView, not bottom layout guide. I have tried expanding the safe area through code but still, nothing worked.

I am using another embedded view controller inside this view.

**Update**

View hierarchy
[image]

Comment: Is your bottom view is direct subview of the view controller root view??? Add screenshot of the view hierarchy.

Comment: yes, it is direct subview to SuperView. But it loads another controller's view as subview.

Comment: @Bilal check my update.

Comment: this looks fine... trying disconnecting embedded view controller and just set the background color of bottom subview. It could be because of your embedded view controller.

Comment: yes, you are right, botomView is filling properly till bottom, but embedded view is not. I am having same issue for all embedded view controllers.

Comment: Make sure your embedded view controllers are connected with superview not bottom or top layout guides. Try with a single view in embedded view controller by setting background colors.

Comment: Yes, embedded view has constraints with super view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164319/discussion-between-ibug-and-bilal).

Comment: I was told this is a bug with Xcode and the safe area, I had the exact same issue with MapKit where I would tie it to the bottom of safe area / superview and that white area would still persist. I never actually got to fix it because I put in a tab bar which hides the white area, but I think someone said disabling safe area and tying the bottom of the view to bottom of superview directly should fix that white area.

Comment: @dinosaysrawr I have tried that too :(

Comment: It is safe area, try to uncheck Safe area layout guides

Comment: I am not using safe area because my app targets iOS 8+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove "safe Area" in any storyboard ViewController. And then set constraints accordingly like this.

[image]  [image]

Comment: How is setting constraints to Safe Area supposed to eliminate the white space?

Comment: I have changed the screenshots.. top and Bottom space to superview will resolve the problem for sure

Comment: It's better now, but now the text references SafeArea for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

As you are providing target 8.0 support you can just remove safe area and provide simple constraint same as below image then your white space will remove for sure.

[image]