# How to get rid of safeAreaInsets on UIScrollview (iOS 11, iPhoneX)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios11, iphone-x

I have a horizontal paging `UIScrollview`, following is my VFL constraints for leading/trailing `H:|-0-[ScrollView]-0-|` (aligned to superview).

I have left/right `safeAreaInsets` on landscape orientation in iPhone X.

Is it a bug? or I am missing any Apple way that these insets will not be applied when we do not need?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am using following to skip content inset adjustment:

```
UIScrollview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

I found that in iOS 11 `UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.always` includes safe area layout guide and apply these margins as insets, so tried `.never` it worked ))

Comment: I guess there is no way to fix this in iOS9? I ran into this issue and found a few ways to counter act the issue but non are really elegant and feel more like a hack. So I assume it was a bug in ios9 - 10 which was addressed in iOS11?

Answer (score 0):

If you set UIScrollview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never, you'll be responsible for applying the insets. If you let to the default value, any time the view needs to be redrawn, the framework will override your settings